# Unresolved Similar Texts: Anomalies in Android Studio's Ctrl + Shift + F Search Results

Tags: android-studio

I have been accustomed for years to using the shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + F` to find similar words in Android Studio. The results have always brought me all the similar words, but suddenly, there are similar texts that are not included in the search. Why is this happening?

[image]